# How can blind users enter (keyboard) characters without resorting to a braille I/O device?

Tags: input-methods, accessibility, text-input

If I am unable to use my eyesight¹ and also unable to use my mouth², then how can I comfortably enter characters into my device using only one free hand?

Suppose TalkBack is enabled. Is there gestures I can perhaps (set up or register and then) use to enter characters or Chinese idiograms into the device (without using the keyboard given that hovering over keyboard keys and having each key sounded out by TalkBack seems awkward and using the keyboard with TalkBack seems unnatural to me at least)?

---

¹ for instance because my screen may be blinded by a very intense outdoors sun or because my eyes may be undergoing adaptation from intense light to dark light environments or vice-versa or because of an accident or because I may be taking part in an experiment requiring me to have my eyes covered with a bandage wrapped around my eyes or because I may have headphones on so as not to make noise and may be sleeping in a place with beds sharing a common room and the light coming from my device would wake others up and lead me into trouble

² for instance I may have a piccolo or other musical mouth instrument in my mouth, or I may be in the situation of a shared bedroom in the dark just described and talking would make noise, or may have a speech disability or disorder

Comment: You asked a lot of different questions here.  I have very tech savvy blind family members, and tech savvy deaf family members, so I'm always interested to participate in these discussions.  If you get some flack for your question being too broad, then I would suggest you split this into multiple questions over a few days and see what the community comes up with for each scenerio.